# How to deserialize only certain properties of JSON data into list in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON data with lots of attributes that I want to deserialize

```
{
  "Senders": [
    {
      "Id": 63465,
      "Title": null,
      "Firstname": "King",
      "Lastname": "Kong",
      "Site": {
        "BSNR": "521112354",
        "Name": "Irgendwo",
        "Address": {
          "Street": null,
          "CountryCode": null,
          "Zip": null,
          "City": null,
          "AddressSupplement": null
        }
      },
      "SpecialField": null,
      "CustomerNo": "KINGKONG",
      "Contact": {
        "Email": null,
        "Phone": "1234",
        "Mobile": null,
        "FaxNumbersInfos": [
          {
            "Id": 324,
            "Fax": "044111111",
            "Description": "Fax 1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "KbvChecksum": null,
      "OrderEntry": {
        "OrderLabelCount": 0,
        "NumberRange": {
          "Id": 9,
          "Part": null
        },
        "OrderNumberAllocationType": 1,
        "LastOrderNumber": 1005
      },
      "LaboratoryId": 190,
      "Note": null,
      "CreatedOn": "2017-11-29T10:11:05",
      "Fullname": "King Kong",
      "PersonStatus": null,
      "SetTakingDateOnOrderApprove": false,
      "IsMemberOfHealthInsuranceCollaborativeLaboratory": false,
      "IsMemberOfPrivateCollaborativeLaboratory": true,
      "HasPvsApproval": false,
      "WouldLikeToIgelInPrivateLg": false,
      "ShowPathoValuesFromLastResult": true,
      "UsesDigitalPatterns": true,
      "AllowPrintAdditionalLabels": true,
      "AllowPrintCostEstimate": false,
      "CostEstimateCount": 0,
      "AllowMultipleFaxNumbers": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 32222,
      "Title": "Herr",
      "Firstname": "Garfield",
      "Lastname": "Lasagne",
      "Site": {
        "BSNR": "198533333",
        "Name": "test",
        "Address": {
          "Street": "Test Str. 32 ",
          "CountryCode": null,
          "Zip": null,
          "City": "33333 Test - Test",
          "AddressSupplement": null
        }
      },
      "SpecialField": " FA f. Allgemeinmedizin",
      "CustomerNo": "KNOR",
      "Contact": {
        "Email": null,
        "Phone": "0233333333",
        "Mobile": null,
        "FaxNumbersInfos": [
          {
            "Id": 284,
            "Fax": "12345",
            "Description": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 285,
            "Fax": "1235213",
            "Description": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 286,
            "Fax": "2352352",
            "Description": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 311,
            "Fax": "232352",
            "Description": null
          },
          {
            "Id": 322,
            "Fax": "534623",
            "Description": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "KbvChecksum": null,
      "OrderEntry": {
        "OrderLabelCount": 0,
        "NumberRange": {
          "Id": null,
          "Part": null
        },
        "OrderNumberAllocationType": 0,
        "LastOrderNumber": null
      },
      "LaboratoryId": 196,
      "Note": null,
      "CreatedOn": "2017-03-30T08:26:03",
      "Fullname": "Garfield Lasagne",
      "PersonStatus": null,
      "SetTakingDateOnOrderApprove": false,
      "IsMemberOfHealthInsuranceCollaborativeLaboratory": false,
      "IsMemberOfPrivateCollaborativeLaboratory": false,
      "HasPvsApproval": false,
      "WouldLikeToIgelInPrivateLg": false,
      "ShowPathoValuesFromLastResult": false,
      "UsesDigitalPatterns": false,
      "AllowPrintAdditionalLabels": false,
      "AllowPrintCostEstimate": false,
      "CostEstimateCount": 0,
      "AllowMultipleFaxNumbers": true
    },
    {
      "Id": 32904,
      "Title": "Dr.",
      "Firstname": "Test",
      "Lastname": "Test",
      "Site": {
        "BSNR": null,
        "Name": "Dr. Test",
        "Address": {
          "Street": null,
          "CountryCode": null,
          "Zip": null,
          "City": null,
          "AddressSupplement": null
        }
      },
      "SpecialField": null,
      "CustomerNo": "SK",
      "Contact": {
        "Email": null,
        "Phone": null,
        "Mobile": null,
        "FaxNumbersInfos": []
      },
      "KbvChecksum": null,
      "OrderEntry": {
        "OrderLabelCount": 0,
        "NumberRange": {
          "Id": 9,
          "Part": null
        },
        "OrderNumberAllocationType": 1,
        "LastOrderNumber": 2016
      },
      "LaboratoryId": 190,
      "Note": null,
      "CreatedOn": "2020-07-23T14:06:40",
      "Fullname": "Seb Kob",
      "PersonStatus": null,
      "SetTakingDateOnOrderApprove": false,
      "IsMemberOfHealthInsuranceCollaborativeLaboratory": false,
      "IsMemberOfPrivateCollaborativeLaboratory": true,
      "HasPvsApproval": false,
      "WouldLikeToIgelInPrivateLg": false,
      "ShowPathoValuesFromLastResult": true,
      "UsesDigitalPatterns": true,
      "AllowPrintAdditionalLabels": true,
      "AllowPrintCostEstimate": false,
      "CostEstimateCount": 0,
      "AllowMultipleFaxNumbers": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried to deserialize everything by creating an object SenderInfo with all the properties and tried

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SenderInfo>>(jsonString);
```

but I get an Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException. Since I don't need all of the data, I'd also prefer to deserialize only certain properties. I'm sure there must be a way to achieve this, maybe through a StringReader or something?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Please add `SenderInfo` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what you have in `SenderInfo`, `List<SenderInfo>>` does not represent your json structure, try something like this:

```
public class SendersContainer 
{
    [JsonProperty("Senders")]
    public List<SenderInfo> Senders { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendersContainer>(jsonString);
```

Comment: @YamgoPango was glad to help!